# How to use javascript in specific jekyll posts?

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I am trying to grab youtube title using [oembed](https://oembed.com/) in jekyll.
This is my code with some errors like `index.js: Unexpected token (3:12)` in codepen. Please correct it.

```
<script>
          function getyoutubetitle(id) {
            var json = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D' + id + '&format=json';
            document.write(json[title]);
          }
      </script>
getyoutubetitle(xh6mpAOD9ho);
```

Please see this [link](http://songs.justinechacko.in/malayalam/2018/02/01/file5.html), Here I called javascript function specifically in post. But it is not working just gives corresponding text like `getyoutubetitle(xh6mpAOD9ho);`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument as a string to start.

getyoutubetitle("xh6mpAOD9ho");

You can also use this node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-youtube-title

Seems a good fit for your use case since you only need the title. I don't think your function is getting any information. If you're not going to use the package, I suggest you look into using the google api. I am sure you'll find JS code snippets in docs.

Use the browser console to debug what the URL is fetching or use Postman to test the proper API.

Comment: I get error in console `title is not defined
    at getyoutubetitle`

Answer (score 0):

1. Javascript must be enclosed in `<script>` tag
2. Id must be passed as a string, not as a variable name

Your code can look like :

```
<script>
getyoutubetitle("xh6mpAOD9ho");
</script>
```

Comment: I get error in console `title is not defined
    at getyoutubetitle`

Comment: Watch your javascript console in browser. Some of your video id are wrong or outdated and returning a 404. So, no json : no title.

Comment: Ok, but I have a doubt Is it possible simply collect a data from url like `var json = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D' + id + '&format=json';`, because it is a remote file?